# How do I expose a function type as a business requirement without exposing its asynchronous dependency?

Tags: f#, domain-driven-design

I prefer to model business requirements as function types within a code base:

```
type Subscribe = SubscribeRequest -> Result<SubscribedCourier,ErrorDescription>
```

Then I implemented a function that complies with a function type:

```
let subscribe : Publish.Subscribe =
    fun request ->

        let subscribed  = request |> toSubscribedCourier
        ...
        Ok subscribed
```

**Issue:**

The above function is fine when implementing a unit test. However, when the above function needs to rely on an external system to complete its task, then I believe that the function requires an *async* modifier for that function signature.

As a result, I'm now obligated to update my function type to the following:

```
type Subscribe = SubscribeRequest -> Async<Result<SubscribedCourier,ErrorDescription>>
```

Thus, my actual function that needs to *await* an external system's response looks like this:

```
let subscribe : Publish.Subscribe =
    fun request ->

        async {

            let subscribed  = request |> toSubscribedCourier
            let json        = JsonConvert.SerializeObject subscribed
            let buffer      = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json)
            let message     = Message(buffer)

            let topicClient = new TopicClient("MyConnectionString","Subscription.subscribed")

            do! topicClient.SendAsync(message) |> Async.AwaitTask
            return Ok subscribed
        }
```

Although, the above function type is correct for returning an Async result type, it's now a leaky abstraction for how the function executes. I really want to only specify business requirements through function types and have my functions map to those function types as if they were contacts.

**Question:**

In conclusion, how do I expose a function type as a business requirement without exposing its asynchronous dependency?

Comment: Not sure I follow. As I see it you have three options. 1. Keep as is, 2. Return a Async<Result<>>, 3. Create a AsyncResult type that is returned. If you go with one you just have to call it synchronously to hide the async stuff. Not sure I think it is that bad to hide that it async though. I think Scott Wlashin has a pretty good example of this in his book.

Comment: You don't want to hide the `Async` type here, it's important to keep the code async top to bottom. When you say "business requirement", I'm assuming you mean "domain model". It's reasonable to keep your domain model code free from `Async`, as async code typically "does something", and domain code is side effect free. So IMO the code you have here is fine.

Comment: @TomasJansson 

I created an AsyncResult type:
type AsyncResult<'a,'e> = Async<Result<'a,'e>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to define a type alias for a function, but I do agree that if you want to implement [a functional architecture](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/11/19/functional-architecture-a-definition), business logic shouldn't be asynchronous. In F# I think that it makes sense to view [asynchronicity as implying impurity](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/04/11/async-as-surrogate-io). You rarely need to return asynchronous workflows unless you're performing I/O.

I think that one should keep the domain model [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), so, as you write, [returning an asynchronous workflow is a leaky abstraction](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/11/asynchronous-injection).

You can often address the issue by refactoring to an **impure-pure-impure sandwich**. This also seems to be the case here. As far as I can tell, the work to actually put a message on a queue looks to be entirely generic. I suppose you could extract that into a helper function, like this:

```
let send x =
    let json        = JsonConvert.SerializeObject x
    let buffer      = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes json
    let message     = Message buffer

    let topicClient = new TopicClient ("MyConnectionString", "Subscription.subscribed")

    do! topicClient.SendAsync message |> Async.AwaitTask
    return Ok x
```

(I haven't tried to compile this, so there may be minor issues.)

You can now create the sandwich as a straightforward composition:

```
let sandwich = toSubscribedCourier >> send
```

(Again, this may not compile, but hopefully gets the point across.)

It's possible that there's little to no logic in `toSubscribedCourier`, but that's just the reality of things, then. As I've written in [a recent article on the same general topic](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/12/02/refactoring-registration-flow-to-functional-architecture):

> Once you remove all the accidental complexity, you uncover the essential complexity.

Perhaps there isn't much domain logic, but that fact is only laid bare once you start separating the pure functions from the impure actions.

Comment: I think I understand your reasoning. I decided to keep the code as-is due to the increased complexity with (little ROI) for what I'm trying to accomplish.